# Nuget "Pack" command in Visual Studio not including the correct dll in the package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Running Visual Studio 2022 Community, following the [directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=nuget#run-the-pack-command) for my project. Right click on the Project in my solution (there are 3 projects in my solution), select "Pack" and it builds just like the directions say. The problem is that it's including the dll from another project in the same solution in the package, and not the one it shows in the output in the console. The dlls are all in the same directory.

Everything I've looked at regarding dlls and nuget talks about getting the dependencies and other files, but not the main thing that's supposed to be packaged.

In addition, I get these two warnings which I looked up, but what I found doesn't make sense to me, or give me a clear idea what I need to do to prevent these errors:

```
NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): warning NU5128: Some target frameworks declared 
in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches 
in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:

NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): warning NU5128: - Add lib or ref assemblies for 
the net7.0 target framework
```

So how do I make sure that the "Pack" command includes the correct dll?

Answer (score 0):

Answer - in the .csproj file, there is a property `<IncludeBuildOutput>`, which was set to `false`, and setting it to true caused the specific dll I am interested in to be included in the install. The .nupkg file added a `lib/Net7.0/mylib.dll` to the contents list.